# Rigid body object sliding too much

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I'm new to blender and wanted to create a bowling scene. Most stuff is going fine but I'm having some problems with the physics of rigid body simulations.

[image: Pins and ball sliding]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXNSF.gif)

As you can see in the above gif, the main issue here is that the pins slide when hit instead of flying about as good pins should. Also, I noticed that the bowling ball doesn't really roll very well down the slope. Everything's far too slippery it seems.

Normally I would assume that meddling with the friction and bounciness is my answer but unfortunately it doesn't seem to help. High friction on the ball makes it slow and unresponsive, and the pins never fall over.

If someone has a fix for this that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For some reason the blend file is 140mb which is insane and I don't know why it's so big because the only things in the scene are what's shown (I even deleted all other objects). That's why I haven't uploaded it

Comment: try increasing the friction of ball, pins and ground. And you can upload to any cloud service you like, e.g. dropbox or whatever

Comment: also maybe try some other masses?

Comment: Ryan King did a bowling tutorial for Blender 2.8 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLaZwf-vBLk) which worked fine from memory so you can see what settings he used in that.

Comment: Okay so... after playing around with blender for a bit I think I found a solution. It still needs some tweaking currently but I get vastly different results when I scale the object up higher. It's annoying because I had the whole model to scale originally but I'm glad I'm finally seeing some results. The friction and bounciness properties did nothing.

Comment: Physics doesn't work well in Blender with small objects. Incidentally the physics section of Ryan Kings article that I mentioned above starts [here](https://youtu.be/CyW14tI7Hqk?t=2193) if you're interested.

Comment: @Confused_User as Chris says, it would be better to share your file so that we can give a try: https://blend-exchange.com/